# Accessing special CP15 c13 Software Thread ID registers in lldb

Tags: arm, lldb

I need to access the special CP15 c13 Software Thread ID ARM registers and could not find other way of doing it within LLDB. I thought of using

```
expr  __asm__ __volatile__("MRC p15, 0, r0, c13, c0, 3");
```

It runs, but has no effect on the content of r0. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on iOS, you can use [`_pthread_self()`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/arm/pthreads/pthread_self.s) to get this value.

Comment: Igor, you saved my day! I'm still looking for the way to do it with assembly. As Jim has explained, the problem with it was that the registers are restored after the expression is executed. If/when I find a way to retrieve the value from r0, this method will work as well.

Comment: Actually, the implementation on the real device is different (and thus it breaks my desired usage:)    # 0x304cb594 <+0>:  mrc    p15, #0x0, r0, c13, c0, #0x3
    # 0x304cb598 <+4>:  bic    r0, r0, #0x3
    # 0x304cb59c <+8>:  ldr    r0, [r0]
    # 0x304cb59e <+10>: bx     lr